# Send with phpmailer a script in php $mail->Body = $PHPorHTML;

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer

How I can send a .html or .php script template for email

```
$HTML= "message.html";
$PHP= "message.php";
$mail->Body = $PHP;
```

this its a example for send https://pm.decolombiajoyas.com/templatemejorado.php

I think generate a html based for send but need more ideas for do it.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Hello, Did that work?

Comment: Yes but not compile php code. I think first compile the PHP code in HTML file. You know any method for do this ? Its similar function of HTML cache.

Comment: No, I am don't know any method for doing this you may search on Google or Ask new question in Stack Overflow. Also Please click on grey check mark next to my answer. :)

Comment: i try do it : $htmlContent = file_get_contents("https://pm.decolombiajoyas.com/templatemejorado.php");

But not work.

The layout work but its bugged in email.

Not apper good.

Comment: Add Screenshoot to what is bugged?

Comment: https://pm.decolombiajoyas.com/Gmail%20-%20%F0%9F%92%8ETenemos%20Nuevos%20Precios%20y%20Dise%C3%B1os%F0%9F%92%8D.pdf  It this, and the real its https://pm.decolombiajoyas.com/templatemejorado.php

Comment: I think that the problem from code of The Templete of PHP not from my script. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple :

```php
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("email_template.html"); // Here add location of file.
mail($htmlContent, ); // Add rest of contents that you want to send.
```